# What does your .conkerorrc look like?

Tags: javascript, firefox, configuration, emacs, conkeror

[Conkeror](http://conkeror.org/) has changed the way I browse the web: it's basically Emacs + Firefox with javascript based configuration in [.conkerrorc](http://conkeror.org/ConkerorRC) rather than elisp configuration in .emacs.

I've built up a huge library of .emacs customizations over the years by getting little bits and pieces from others. I'm just starting with Conkeror but the fact that it uses JS (far more widely known than Elisp) must mean that there's some amazing stuff out there.

Care to share your pieces? **I'm particularly interested in stuff that interacts well with pages produced by Django (or other dynamic web pages).**

For example, I'd love a Conkeror-based action recorder that let me browse a site and find bugs, and then immediately save & submit the sequence of actions as a bug report with a single keystroke. By including the JS actions required to replicate the error, it would be the ultimate testing harness -- even better than Selenium because it would be totally keyboard driven.

Comment: Why the votes to close? This is very similar to the threads asking for tips on Emacs/elisp customization: 

http://i.stackoverflow.com/questions/41522/tips-for-learning-elisp/156861

Comment: You've opened a bounty on this, but it's not at all clear that this question has a definitive answer. I'd vote to close, too, if I had the rep for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no one else seems interested in posting an actual reply, I will.

```
function my_title_format (window) {
   return 'conkeror {'+get_current_profile()+'}'+window.buffers.current.description;
}
```

I find it helpful to have the profile name in the window title as I use multiple profiles. It doesn't help me so much now that I use [StumpWM](http://www.nongnu.org/stumpwm/) and don't look at the window list much, but it's very helpful in other window managers.

```
define_key(content_buffer_normal_keymap, "C-x C-c", "confirm-quit");
can_kill_last_buffer = false;
```

These two keep me from accidentally closing a conkeror window by closing the last buffer.

Answer (score 6):

Here's mine:

```
// homepage = "http://www.google.com";

// set default webjump
read_url_handler_list = [read_url_make_default_webjump_handler("google")];
// possibly valid URL
function possibly_valid_url (str) {
    return (/[\.\/:]/.test(str)) &&
        !(/\S\s+\S/.test(str)) &&
        !(/^\s*$/.test(str));
}

// page modes
require("page-modes/google-search-results.js"); // google search results
require("page-modes/wikipedia.js");     // wikipedia mode

// webjumps
define_webjump("gmail", "https://mail.google.com"); // gmail inbox
define_webjump("twitter", "http://twitter.com/#!/search/%s", $alternative = "https://twitter.com/");  // twitter
define_webjump("w3schools", "http://www.w3schools.com"); // w3schools site
define_webjump("w3search", "http://www.google.com/search?sitesearch=www.w3schools.com&as_q=%s"); // w3schools search
define_webjump("jquery", "http://docs.jquery.com/Special:Search?ns0=1&search=%s"); // jquery
define_webjump("archwiki", "https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?search=%s"); // arch wiki
define_webjump("stackoverflow", "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%s", $alternative = "http://stackoverflow.com/"); // stackoverflow
define_webjump("sor", "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+%s", $alternative = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r"); // stackoverflow R section
define_webjump("stats", "http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%s"); // stats
define_webjump("torrentz", "http://torrentz.eu/search?q=%s"); // torrentz
define_webjump("avaxsearch", "http://avaxsearch.com/avaxhome_search?q=%s&a=&c=&l=&sort_by=&commit=Search"); // avaxsearch
define_webjump("imdb", "http://www.imdb.com/find?s=all;q=%s"); // imdb
define_webjump("duckgo", "http://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s", $alternative = "http://duckduckgo.com"); // duckduckgo
define_webjump("blekko", "http://blekko.com/ws/%s", $alternative = "http://blekko.com/"); // blekko
define_webjump("youtube", "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%s&aq=f", $alternative = "http://www.youtube.com"); // youtube
define_webjump("duckgossl", "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s"); // duckduckgo SSL
define_webjump("downforeveryoneorjustme", "http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/%s"); // downforeveryoneorjustme
define_webjump("urbandictionary", "http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=%s"); // urban dictionary
define_webjump("rts", "http://rts.rs");             // RTS
define_webjump("facebook", "http://www.facebook.com");      // facebook homepage

// tab bar
require("new-tabs.js");

// clicks in new buffer
require("clicks-in-new-buffer.js");
// Set to either OPEN_NEW_BUFFER(_BACKGROUND)
clicks_in_new_buffer_target = OPEN_NEW_BUFFER_BACKGROUND; // Now buffers open in background.

// history webjump
define_browser_object_class(
    "history-url", null, 
    function (I, prompt) {
        check_buffer (I.buffer, content_buffer);
        var result = yield I.buffer.window.minibuffer.read_url(
            $prompt = prompt,  $use_webjumps = false, $use_history = true, $use_bookmarks = false);
        yield co_return (result);
    });

interactive("find-url-from-history",
            "Find a page from history in the current buffer",
            "find-url",
            $browser_object = browser_object_history_url);

interactive("find-url-from-history-new-buffer",
            "Find a page from history in the current buffer",
            "find-url-new-buffer",
            $browser_object = browser_object_history_url);

define_key(content_buffer_normal_keymap, "h", "find-url-from-history-new-buffer");
define_key(content_buffer_normal_keymap, "H", "find-url-from-history");

// load session module
require("session.js");
session_auto_save_auto_load = true; // auto-load session

// don't open download buffer automatically
remove_hook("download_added_hook", open_download_buffer_automatically);

// don't show clock
remove_hook("mode_line_hook", mode_line_adder(clock_widget));

// add favicons
require("favicon");
add_hook("mode_line_hook", mode_line_adder(buffer_icon_widget), true);
read_buffer_show_icons = true;

// add content handlers
content_handlers.set("application/pdf", content_handler_save); // pdf
// torrent
// mp3
// ogg

function define_switch_buffer_key (key, buf_num) {
    define_key(default_global_keymap, key,
               function (I) {
           switch_to_buffer(I.window,
                                    I.window.buffers.get_buffer(buf_num));
               });
}
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    define_switch_buffer_key(String((i+1)%10), i);
}

function enable_scrollbars (buffer) {
    buffer.top_frame.scrollbars.visible = true;
}
add_hook("create_buffer_late_hook", enable_scrollbars);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't really help you here but I just wanted to say that although I'm an emacs guy, I dropped Conkeror for [vimperator](http://vimperator.org) because IMHO the browsing experience is much better!

Answer (score -2):

Conkeror is merely Firefox with Emacs keybindings.  I don't think it is, and nor does it intend to be, a fully featured environment as Emacs is.

It facilitates your browsing experience by allowing you to use your well-worn Emacs muscle memory.  And lets you keep your hands on the keyboard more, instead of jumping from keyboard to mouse all the time.

So I don't think it is really capable of doing some of the things you imagine.

Its development is also rather slow and is probably understaffed.  You'll find, for example, that you can't use most common Firefox addons/extensions with it. Firebug, Greasemonkey, Gears, etc.

I do like it for some browsing tasks: it has special modes for reading Reddit, Google Reader, and others that make things a lot easier.

But I also agree with binOr that vimperator is much better, even if you're an emacs guy.  Helps if you use VIM of course.

Comment: The development team may be small but we're scrappy! :-) Since it has a full Turing complete language for configuration and is, in fact, written in JS you can do just about anything you want as to it. Besides, it's sort of a pain to try to bludgeon primarily mouse driven extensions such as Firebug into working with the keyboard. And what would you need Greasemonkey for since you already have access to the DOM with JS anyway?

Comment: Also, you can't use many Firefox extensions because Conkeror is not Firefox. They are both based on xulrunner, but many extensions, like Firebug, rely on Firefox's chrome.